# Backup folder and files in a server location to another location on a server

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a backup of a huge directory in a server location with. It takes time to even calculate the size of the folder. Basically I want to copy everything in that location to another location and need to do this every week to make a backup. I have the following code so far which would copy everything from one location to another including folder, sub-folders and files. But I am hesitant to try this on a server location because so far we have no backup and something goes wrong we can loose everything. Is there a way to track the progress of folders being copied in status bar to see the code is still working and there are no errors.

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Test\Design Documents - Original"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Test\Design Documents - Backup"    '<< Change

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "Data Copied from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

As a longtime IT guy, this makes me cringe. Server backups are NOT a job for Excel and VBA. There is no possible good answer to this question that involves Excel.

Your server admins should be using a backup/syncing tool that is designed to work with servers. There are numerous choices to fit different needs and budgets.

My advice would be, if the job has fallen to you, to hire an IT company that could set up a reliable and efficient backup system for you.